# How to decipher this Microphone sensitivity Chart for Choosing a SPL meter

Tags: filters, frequency, sound

I have a mic having sensitivity chart as below which has relative dB on y-axis showing

> 1V/0.1Pa

what does this convey how to read my mic's sensitivity

a document on microphone sensitivity from [analog](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/46-05/understanding_microphone_sensitivity.pdf) says the microphone sensitivity is measure with 1Pa pressure as reference

confused in half way after seeing my datasheet of mic

[image]

usually i was of the opinion that the microphone sensitivity is measure with reference to 20micropascals,but i read with this SPL measurements
so i am wrong

so if i have to buy an SPL i have to correlate my SPL with the microphone i am using

because if my microphone i am using in my application picks up some sound according to its sensitivity and the spl meter i am purchasing may not give me the required SPL level that i have detected

when i have seen the frequency Weighting curves of the SPL meter they are shown as below

[image]

what do these convey ? are they trying to attenuate some frequencies or they are trying to follow human auditory model

so if i have to buy an SPL meter having correlative sensitivity as of my microphone would be better,what is your opinion am i going the right way in selection of an SPL

Answer (score 2):

Microphones are typically specified in dB re 1 V/Pa. So am microphone with a sensitivity -44 dB (like this one http://www.panasonic.com/industrial/electronic-components/parametric-search.aspx?src=/www-cgi/jvcr13pz.cgi?E%2BSS%2B2%2BABA5010%2B0%2B4%2BAM) would produce 6.3mV RMS at 1 Pa of sound pressure. 1 Pa also corresponds to 94 dBSPL. So you can easily convert dB SPL in dB Pa by subtracting 94.

The datasheet for our microphone looks strange. I have never seen unit of 1.0V/0.1Pa before. This is potentially a print error.

The weighting curves do indeed mimic the frequency response of the human auditory system at different overall levels. However they are all 0 dB at 1 kHz, so if you calibrate at 1 kHz the weighting doesn't matter.

Comment: if i consider the reference as correct then my sensitivity would become 39mV/Pa,if i consider this as a typo then 4mV/Pa but my microphone is so sensitive than the microphone you have shown me this is from knowless (FB30346)

Answer (score 2):

The ref. unit mentioned is perfectly fine. Some microphone manufacturers use 1 dyne/cm^2. This would translate into -74 dB instead of -94 dB because the reference pressure applied is 0.1 Pa. So you can do the same math, just subtract -20 dB. To resume: to calculate the sensitivity you must: 20.*log10(sens.)-20. In you case, this would imply a sensitivity (sens. according to above notation) of about 40 mv/Pa, as you mentioned.